# Date-time axis working as string, not as proper continuous date/time axis in Zing Chart

Tags: datetime, charts, zingchart

I am plotting date-time vs integer in ZingChart. Even if there is difference of one second or the difference of 1 hour, the width is same between the two points. If the starting time is same as the previous one, like in my attached image at 23:24:40, there should not a white gap in between if it is proper date and time axis. Is there any solution to this problem? You can also view it on alnnovative.com/zing6.php
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ZingChart will automatically place values at each index, unless you use key, value pairs as your data points. To do this, set your series object values like so:

```
"values":[
    [1420070400000,50],
    [1420071000000,50],
    [1420070520000,50],
    [1420070640000,50],
    [1420070700000,50],
    [1420070760000,50],
    [1420070820000,50],
    [1420070940000,50],
    [1420071060000,50]
]
```

Take a look at [this demo](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/SF0EAE8Q). I'm a member of the ZingChart team, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you. It's working exactly in the same way as I wanted.