# Two charts and one preview in ZingChart

Tags: charts, zingchart

I have 2 charts that have the same x-axis, I want one preview and when I scroll that, the 2 charts should scroll at the same time, is this feature available in ZingChart?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This demo](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/WJOYASDV) should include all the elements you need:

- 2 charts that share an x-axis
- A preview window that controls the two charts
- A scroll bar that controls both charts and the preview window area

You can view the source in the demo to see that we added:

- `{graphset: [ ]}` to create a collection of charts in a single container
- `zooming: true` to the scaleX object for each chart
- `zoom: {
    shared: true
  }`  for each chart to enable sharing
- `scrollX:{ }` to the second chart to add the scroll bar
- `crosshairX:{ 
    shared: true 
  }` for shared labels when hovering over the data points

I’m on the ZingChart team. Please let me know if this demo answers your question or if there is additional clarification I can provide.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is actually what I wanted. Being on the team, can you please look at my another question and let me know if this feature is available or not? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608347/date-time-axis-working-as-string-not-as-proper-continuous-date-time-axis-in-zin

Comment: Hi Marium Malik, it looks like your question was addressed by another team member. Hope that helped! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, someone has replied. Thanks